# c++ Using C99 complex with FFTW in C++14

Tags: c++, c++14, complex-numbers, fftw

I'm having trouble using the C99 `complex` data type with FFTW and C++14.

```
// fftw14.cc
#include <complex.h>
#include <fftw3.h>

int main() {
    fftw_complex* in;

    in  = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * 100);

    in[0] = 1337.42;

    return 0;
}
```

There is no problem when I compile it with `g++ fftw14.cc -lfftw3 -lm`. However, using C++14 (`g++ -std=c++14 fftw14.cc -lfftw3 -lm`), `fftw_complex` gets `double[2]` and hence the implicit typecast fails.

```
fftw14.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
fftw14.cc:11:8: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘double’ to ‘fftw_complex {aka double [2]}’
  in[0] = 1337.42;
        ^
```

Why is that? I know I could mess around with the `std::complex<double>` type, but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: `fftw_complex` changes its definition depending on a few things read http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Complex-numbers.html carefully. I think this bit _"if you #include <complex.h> before <fftw3.h>, then fftw_complex is defined to be the native complex"_ is confusing as it only applies to the `C` compiler, and does not state what happens with `C++`.

Comment: You should be using `static_cast` or `reinterpret_cast` to more clearly express your intent. C-style casts are frowned upon usually.

Comment: What bugs me, is that it works with C++98 but not with C++14. I want to understand what could cause this.